# Mapping the same url to different methods based on request body in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to know if it's possible to map the same URL to different methods in the `RestController` class, based only in the request body. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public void delete(@RequestBody String id) {
    //do something
}

@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public void delete(@RequestBody Book book) {
    //do something
}
```

The request body will always be a JSON payload. if it's `{"id":"foo"}` I want the first method to be called. If the request body is:

```
{
    "title":"Spring Guide",
    "author":"John Doe"
}
```

I want the second method to be called. Is this possible?

Comment: No. You cannot differentiate based on payload.

Comment: Based on your code snippets, creating a `DELETE` handler on `/books/{id}` seems more suitable.

Comment: You can try this : Have single annotated method handle both JSON Payload  by passing them as Object i.e. `@RequestBody Object obj` and then convert it into `String` or `Book` to delete it.

Comment: Yeah, I evetually changed the code to what  Ali Dehghani suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate only by payload.

Based on the tests I did here and M. Deinum and Ali Dehghani's response I think the best way to do this is to have different urls for each case. So a `/books/{id}` to delete by the id, and a `/books` with the object's JSON in the body to delete passing the object. Thanks for all that commented.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question asked. An answer would be "no, it's not possible to differentiate based on payload".