# Distinguish Spring Boot PostMapping based on key in RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST endpoint with a PostMapping that should be able to accept different objects in the body and map them based on existence of keys.

When I use the same PostMapping for both functions, it gives me an "Ambiguous mapping" error.

When I use params similar to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping, the default mapping is called even if the specialKey exists in the request body.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/classes", params = {"specialKey"})
public ResponseEntity<Class> createClass(@Valid @RequestBody SpecialClass class) throws URISyntaxException {
    // do something special
}

@PostMapping("/classes")
public ResponseEntity<Class> createClass(@Valid @RequestBody Class class) throws URISyntaxException {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Mapping the same url to different methods based on request body in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483664/mapping-the-same-url-to-different-methods-based-on-request-body-in-spring) it's not possible (or at least wasn't at the time). The `params` needs a separate request parameter, it can't be used to look for things inside the request body like that.

You *could* include the parameter in the URI, the special endpoint would be `/classes?specialKey`, and the normal endpoint just `/classes`. But I would just use different paths.